# Idiomatic way of forcing set -e everywhere in a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, error-handling

Let's imagine we have this code (`script.sh`):

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

f() {
  echo "[f] Start"  >&2
  echo "f:before-false1"
  echo "f:before-false2"
  false
  echo "f:after-false"
  echo "[f] Fail! I don't want this executed" >&2
}

out=$(f)
```

The output:

```
$ bash myscript.sh
[f] Start
[f] Fail! I don't want this executed
```

I understand that `$(...)` starts a sub-shell where `set -e` is not propagated, so my question is: what's the idiomatic way to make this run as expected without too much clutter? I can see 3 solutions, none of which I like (nor I am actually sure they indeed work): 1) Add `set -e` to the start of `f` (and every other function in the app). 2) Run `$(set -e && f)`. 3) Add `... || return 1` to every command that may fail.

Comment: Option 3 is actually a [good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105).

Comment: @chepner: Good read. `cmd || return 1` is explicit and conceptually ok, but so cumbersome...

Answer (score 2):

It's not the prettiest solution, but it does allow you to emulate `set -e` for the current shell *as well as any functions and subshells*:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up an ERR trap that unconditionally exits with a nonzero exit code.
# Similar to -e, this trap is invoked when a command reports a nonzero
# exit code (outside of a conditional / test).
# Note: This trap may be called *multiple* times. 
trap 'exit 1' ERR

# Now ensure that the ERR trap is called not only by the current shell,
# but by any subshells too:
# set -E (set -o errtrace) causes functions and subshells to inherit
# ERR traps.
set -E    

f() {
  echo "[f] Start"  >&2
  echo "f:before-false1"
  echo "f:before-false2"
  false
  echo "f:after-false"
  echo "[f] Fail! I don't want this executed" >&2
}

out=$(f)
```

Output (to stderr) if you call this script (exit code afterward will be `1`) - note how the 2nd `echo` to stderr (`>&2`) is *not* printed, proving that the execution of `false` aborted the command substitution:

```
[f] Start
```

Note:

- By design, `set -e` / `trap ERR` only respond to failures that aren't part of *conditionals* (see `man bash`, under the description of `set` (search for literal " set ["), for the exact rules, which changed slightly between Bash 3.x and 4.x).

  - Thus, for instance, `f` does NOT trigger the trap in the following commands: `if ! f; then ...`, `f && echo ok`; the following triggers the trap *in the subshell* (command substitution `$(...)`, but not in the enclosing conditional (`[[ ... ]]`): `[[ $(f) == 'foo' ]] && echo ok`, so the script *as a whole* doesn't abort.
  - To exit a function / subshell *explicitly* in such cases, use something like `|| return 1` / `|| exit 1`, or call the function / subshell *separately*, *outside* of a conditional first; e.g., in the `[[ $(f) == 'foo' ]]` case: `res=$(f); [[ $res == 'foo' ]]` - `res=$(f)` will then trigger the trap for the current shell too.
- As for why the `trap` code may be invoked *multiple* times: In the case at hand, `false` *inside* `f()` *first* triggers the trap, and then, because the trap's `exit 1` exits the *subshell* (`$(f)`), the trap is triggered *again* for the *current* shell (the one running the script).

Comment: Thanks! I had tested with `trap ... ERR`, but `set -E` was missing to make it work. I think it's a pretty cool workaround, you don't need to change the code itself.

Comment: I have problems when `f` is called from an if: `if ! f; then echo "f failed"; fi` -> `[f] Fail! I don't want this executed`

Comment: @tokland: I'm afraid that's by design - please see my update.

Comment: Interesting use of `set -E` and well explained answer ++

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *command substitution*, you should use [process substitution](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) to call your function so that `set -e` remains in effect:

```
mapfile arr < <(f)   # call function f using process substitution
out="${arr[*]}"         # convert array content into a string
declare -p out          # check output
```

**Output:**

```
[f] Start
declare -- out="f:before-false1
 f:before-false2
"
```

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about this approach. A bit cumbersome to write, though. I'll add some echos to `f` to make `declare -p out` show something meaningful.

Comment: Yes that's correct output because after that `false` command makes function `f` exit.

Comment: Interesting alternative - `set -e` indeed applies to the commands inside a _process_ substitution as well (as opposed to a _command_ substitution), though a failure there won't abort the script as a whole. Note that the commands in a process substitution run in a _subshell too_, which you can verify as follows: `f() { echo $((++v)); }; v=1; cat <(f); echo "$v"`

Comment: Yes you're right. So `set -e` is in effect for subshell from process substitution but not from command substitution